# Luigi - parallel branches

Tags: python, parallel-processing, luigi

i am completly new to Luigi and i already have a problem that i can't seem to fix.

So let's say i want something like this :

[image]
So basically my question is: how can icall a Task multiple times for as many instances as i want and even keep adding other tasks the same way to each "branch".

I know it should work with the `requires()` function, e.g. by `return [list of Task for x in range(10)]`
or something like this. But i cant find the right syntax / ways of doing it.

I hope someone can help me, i'd be very grateful !!

Best regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uniqueness of the task is determined by the output path. If the output path is the same, then the task is the same. So what you can do is make multiple instances of the same class with different output paths.

The recommended way to do this in Luigi is to add a parameter to your task class and use this parameter in the construction of your output path.

For example,

```
class TaskA(luigi.Task):
    number = luigi.IntParameter()
    
    def output():
        base_path = 'path/to/a/dir' 
        file_name = '%5.5d.txt' % self.number
        return LocalTarget(os.path.join(base_path, file_name))
```

Now you can call this task several times in another task by:

```
class TaskB(luigi.Task):
    
    def requires():
        return [TaskA(i) for i in range(n)]
```

Note, the second time you run `TaskB` its requirements for `TaskA` for 1 to n are already satisfied. If you always want to execute `TaskA` again you should add some randomness to its output path.

Comment: Thanks ! That was exactly what i was searching for :)